# Arm Assembly on RaspberryPi. How to write into RAM and print it out to check it is there?

Tags: c, assembly, arm, raspberry-pi3

I am very new to assembly language, and i need help on writing it to RAM. Right now, i found some codes that i am able to write into a buffer. But how do i write it into RAM with user input, and printf it out to see whether it is there?

Is there a physical address for the RAM that i can stored the user input?

I need to retain the values inside the RAM/physical memory address, even after closing and reopening the program.

i have tried how to move it into register and to buffer.

```
.data

format: .asciz "%s"

string: .asciz "Output: %s\n"
prompt: .asciz ">"

storage: .space 80          @ --- added buffer

.text
.global main
main:                       @ --- removed .

    ldr r0, addr_prompt     /*loading address of prompt message in r0*/
    bl printf               /*calling printf*/

    ldr r0, addr_format     /*loading first parameter of scanf*/
    ldr r1, addr_storage    @ --- location to write data from input
    bl scanf                /*calling scanf*/

    /*below I am trying to print out the user
    input from scanf*/

    ldr r1, addr_storage    @ --- data location
    ldr r0, addr_string     @ --- printf format
    bl printf

    mov r0, #0              @ --- good return code
    mov r7, #1
    swi 0

addr_prompt: .word prompt
addr_format: .word format
addr_string: .word string
addr_storage: .word storage @ --- address of buffer
```

Comment: What do you mean by "_writing it to RAM_"? Assumed that you translate the source code with the onboard assembler and launch the resulting executable, the instructions as well as the variables are already in RAM during runtime.

Comment: I would like to retain the value in the RAM/physical memory address, even after closing and reopening the program.

Comment: Please add this important information to your question by [edit]ing it. So do you actually want to run the program a first time, save some data at a specific RAM location that is maintained even after quitting the program, and when the program is run again can be obtained from there? -- Why does it need to be RAM? Can't you save the data in a file or other OS-provided service? -- You might like to research "shared memory", which might exists as long as the OS runs, independent of other processes accessing it.

Comment: Yes, that is correct - I want to run a program the first time, save some data at a specific RAM location that is maintained even after quitting the program, due to some personal constraints. Currently I am only able to take reference from the linked site; https://www.instructables.com/GPIO-ARM-ASSEMBLY-TI-ROBOTICS-SYSTEM-LEARNING-KIT-/.

Comment: It seems as if that site works with a "bare metal" system, where you have total control of the system. This is not comparable with the PI. Please use the same target system or adjust your goal.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have researched more about this topic and I have found other people using mmap as a way to store the value inside the RAM/physical memory address. Would that be a viable way and if so, how would i go about it?

Comment: Well, this is some homework for you,according to ["How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please search the web and read, experiment, and learn. If you have a specific problem while doing so, feel free to ask another question or to enhance this one.

Comment: I ofc have done some research on myself. And i cant find anything which is why i am posting this question to clear my doubts. thanks for the reply and effort to help out.

Comment: If you're running your code as a user-space process under Linux on your RPi, you can't use physical addresses directly.  Linux uses virtual memory, and your process's virtual address space is not persistent across runs of the same executable.  Things that are persistent are file contents (easiest), or some special files like POSIX shared memory (basically just an mmapped file in tmpfs, with some system calls like `shm_open`, but that's really just `open` and you still have to `mmap` it yourself.).

Comment: If you want an ARM system that lets you write to arbitrary memory try VisualBoyAdvance